# Is there any way to apply trigger on sequence in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, sequence

I am new to Oracle.I have two different sequence.I want to increase the value of second sequence on first sequence nextval call.My requirement is I want to do at database level.

**EDIT:**

old sequence is having max value `999` and new sequence is having `9999999`.For sequence with max value `999` I have to reset the sequence when it reaches to `999`.I have 3 application simultaneously running.2 are using old sequence and 1 is using new sequence.So I want both sequence to be in sync.

Comment: Please post both the Sequence definition. Also Why you are using 2 diff seq? Why not only 1?

Comment: Is it a matter of ensuring the two sequences do not conflict?  Why not just give the new sequence a `MINVALUE` of 1000?

Comment: What do you mean by `both sequence must be in sync`? If one sequence is reset after 999 but the other is not, then they never be in sync after 999.